# django createsuperuser not working in Chrome or IE

Tags: django, django-admin

I am new to Django. created a super user using manage.py createsuperuser. Can log into the site in Firefox, every time, but never in Chrome or IE, the login popup keeps popping up. The only time it worked was when I used manage.py clearsessions. Not working anymore. Cleaned the session by going into sqlite still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... cookie settings? Django doesn't use [cookie-based sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions) by default, but that login form probably does have a [CSRF cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/) in it. If it keeps rejecting your login over and over on different browsers, it could be because you have those browsers set not to take the cookie.